# White light to blue light

Tags: visible-light

When white light falls on a blue colored translucent material and passes through it the light changes its color into blue.Similar phenomenon is observed when yellow light passes through red glass in a car's back lights.Why does this happen?Why does the color of light change?

Comment: Guess:May be red glass transmit red colour and absorbs all other colour.

Comment: @Paul-Do you mean that red glass absorbs all other color except red light and only red light is visible?

Comment: Yes.I meant that.

Comment: @Paul-I think you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White light is a mixture of all wavelengths in visible spectrum. The blue glass has a property to absorb all colors except blue.Hence only blue is transmitted and thus the light seems to be blue.Similarly that yellow light might not be pure ad must be containing some amount of red light,which gets transmitted singlehandedly.I hope this helps!